# Set template based on query in URL

Tags: templates, hooks, urls

I want to be able to force WordPress to load an page/post based on a query in the URL.

`www.mywordpresssite.com/posts/myarticle?template=custom`

This URL should load the *myarticle* post using template `custom.php`

I don't even know where to start with this one. Is there a hook I can use to change the template in my theme before it loads?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of [template filters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Filter_Hierarchy) available to override template selection. For a single post you can use the [`single_template`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/single_template) filter:

```
function wpa_single_template( $template ) {
     if( isset( $_GET['template'] ) ) {
          $template = locate_template( $_GET['template'] . '.php', false );
     }
     return $template;
}
add_filter( 'single_template', 'wpa_single_template' );
```

Comment: Is there a hook before that so that I can apply the logic to all queries, not just ones of a specific template?

Comment: @McShaman The `template_include` filter will run last, letting you modify the template for every type of query.